# Undefined Nested Attributes for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

Please help me fix this error:

> NoMethodError in Quantifieds#index
>   undefined method `results' for nil:NilClass

I am a novice so hopefully this will take you far less time and be far more pleasurable to solve.

**Full trace below**

I gave a lot of code because I don't know how deep the problem goes. I've spent 20+ hours trying to fix it with no luck in *site*. Yet I still think the solution is simple I just need someone with fresh eyes and more experience.

To restate the question, how do I define date_value & result_value so it works in the quantifieds index?

```html
<table>
  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <% if averaged.user == current_user %>
        <th class="value">
          <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %>
          <%= averaged.name %>
          <% end %>
          (<%= averaged.metric %>)
        </th>
  <tbody class="value"> 
      <% @quantifieds.results.each do |result| %>
        <%= result.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %>
        <%= result.result_value %>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
<table>
  <% @instance_quantifieds.each do |instance| %>
    <% if instance.user == current_user %>
        <th class="value">
          <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(instance) do %>
          <%= instance.name %>
          <% end %>
          (<%= instance.metric %>)
        </th>
  <tbody class="value"> 
      <% @quantifieds.results.each do |result| %>
        <%= result.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %>
        <%= result.result_value %>
      <% end %>
  </tbody>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>

  <%= link_to new_quantified_path, class: 'btn'  do %>
  <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"</span></b>
  <% end %>
```

date_value & result_value are derived from :results in the _form. I am using **[cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)** to create my nested attributes.

```html
<%= form_for @quantified do |f| %>
      <%= f.select :categories, Quantified::CATEGORIES %>
        <%= f.text_field :name,  class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Name' %>
        <%= f.text_field :metric,  class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Metric' %>
      <%= f.fields_for :results do |result| %>
      <%= render 'result_fields', :f => result %>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add result', f, :results %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

```html
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.text_field :result_value, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Result' %>
    <%= f.date_select :date_value, :order => [:month, :year], class: 'date-select' %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Result", f %>
</div>
```

Do I need to alter anything in the controller?

```html
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @quantified = Result.order("date_value").all
   @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
   @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :name, :metric, :result, :date, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Here's some more code to give more context:

**routes.rb**

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :goals

  resources :values

  resources :quantifieds

  resources :results

  devise_for :users
  root 'values#index'
  get "about" => "pages#about"
```

**schema.rb**

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150123210404) do

  create_table "quantifieds", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "categories"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "metric"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "quantifieds", ["categories"], name: "index_quantifieds_on_categories"
  add_index "quantifieds", ["user_id"], name: "index_quantifieds_on_user_id"

  create_table "results", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "result_value"
    t.date     "date_value"
    t.integer  "quantified_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "results", ["date_value"], name: "index_results_on_date_value"
  add_index "results", ["user_id"], name: "index_results_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
```

**_create_results.rb**

```html
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.string :result_value
      t.date :date_value
      t.belongs_to :quantified, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :results, :quantifieds
  end
end
```

**_add_user_id_to_results.rb**

```html
class AddUserIdToResults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :results, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :results, :user_id
  end
end
```

**quantified.rb**

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'averaged') }
    scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'instance') }
    has_many :results
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

    CATEGORIES = ['averaged', 'instance']

end
```

**result.rb**

```html
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quantified
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help. It will be enormously appreciated!

**Full Trace** To new error message:

```html
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:99:in `method_missing'
app/views/quantifieds/index.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_quantifieds_index_html_erb__3823335262543476951_70160225385540'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
app/views/quantifieds/index.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_quantifieds_index_html_erb__3823335262543476951_70160225385540'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important in a question needing debugging to supply code, but the rule is it needs to be the *absolute minimum* necessary to reproduce the problem. This isn't the absolute minimum. Please reduce it; Doing so will encourage others to provide answers. As is you're going to drive them away because nobody wants to read through all that.

Comment: totally agree with @theTinMan, I actually downvoted first, but then saw the new user and removed it. Next time, please make sure you specified only related pieces of code and don't attach useless code snippets.

Comment: Sorry @theTinMan & Rustam, as you can tell I love code ;) but I'll reduce it in the future I didn't realize my attempt at helpfulness could get in the way of getting answers

Comment: I'd recommend doing it now, rather than sometime in the future on a different question, since it's affecting this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you iterate with:

```
@quantifieds.results.each do |result|
```

In your index action you got

```
@quantified = Result.order("date_value").all
```

I guess it should be

```
@quantifieds = Result.order("date_value").all
```

Comment: Thanks @Rustam! But now I got this error: undefined method `results' for #<Result::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9ee3737470>. Can you help me with this? I added full trace above.

Comment: @CodeLover of course,  your variable name is misleading, you fetch `Result.order...` and get `@results`, not `@quantifieds`, `results belongs_to :quantified`, `quantified has_many results` and now you basically do `@results.results`

Comment: Thanks @Rustam. I follow your logic but you lost me in what I should do? I tried replacing '@quantifieds' with '@results with = Result.order("date_value").all', but that just gave me a different error. Keep it up with your blog btw.

Comment: Like @RustamA.Gasanov says, your `@quantifields` value contains object of class `Result` already, so there is no need to do anything about it. You fetch `Result` objects in the controller by doing `@quantified = Result.order(...)`. which line in the html file causes the exception - can you show us how exactly the line looks like?

Comment: @AdamNowakv Line 18: <% '@quantifieds.results.each do |result| %>'

Comment: @AdamNowak I started a new question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183052/undefined-method-for-activerecordrelation-nested-attributes) because I felt Rustam solved this one.